Не выводится третий символ
Задача следующая:

На входе вводится строка из букв, следующим вводим число, которое будет означать длину последовательности, чьи варианты будут искаться в строке.
Нужно вывести все варианты в виде списка. Например, если введём AFGTYAFTGAF, а затем ввёдем число 2, то нужно будет ввести все уникальные встречаемые варианты без повторов, точнее: AF, FG, GT, GY и так далее.

У меня следующий код:
seq = input().upper()

k_mer = int(input())

list = []

n = 0

for i in seq:

    seq = seq[n:len(seq)]
    k = seq[0:k_mer]
    if k not in list and k != '':
        list.append(k)
    n += 1

print(list)

Начал с проверки для числа 1 и уже не получается.
Так, при вводе, например, AGTC, код почему-то не видит третью букву Т при числе, но если строку удлинить до AGTCAGTC, только тогда выведет и то в последнюю очередь.
При чём использовать нужно только самые простые функции типа append, find, for.

Добавляем отладочную печать:
...
    seq = seq[n:len(seq)]
    print('seq', seq, 'n', n)  # отладка
    k = seq[0:k_mer]
...


$ echo -e 'AGTC\n1' | python temp.py
seq 'AGTC' n 0
seq 'GTC' n 1
seq 'C' n 2
seq '' n 3
['A', 'G', 'C']

$ echo -e '112123123412345123456\n1' | python temp.py
seq '112123123412345123456' n 0
seq '12123123412345123456' n 1
seq '123123412345123456' n 2
seq '123412345123456' n 3
seq '12345123456' n 4
seq '123456' n 5
seq '' n 6
seq '' n 7
seq '' n 8
seq '' n 9
seq '' n 10
seq '' n 11
seq '' n 12
seq '' n 13
seq '' n 14
seq '' n 15
seq '' n 16
seq '' n 17
seq '' n 18
seq '' n 19
seq '' n 20
['1']


Второй пример показывает проблему: сперва от строки отщипывается один символ (всё в порядке), затем два (значит один пропустили), затем три (два пропустили). Скоро строка кончается, и цикл работает в холостую, но это уже не важно. Откусывать надо по одному символу и делать это в конце цикла:
...
for i in seq:

    print('seq', repr(seq), 'n', n)  # отладка
    k = seq[0:k_mer]
    if k not in list and k != '':
        list.append(k)
    n += 1
    seq = seq[1:len(seq)]  # один символ долой
...


$ echo -e 'AGTC\n1' | python temp.py
seq 'AGTC' n 0
seq 'GTC' n 1
seq 'TC' n 2
seq 'C' n 3
['A', 'G', 'T', 'C']

$ echo -e '112123123412345123456\n1' | python temp.py
seq '112123123412345123456' n 0
seq '12123123412345123456' n 1
seq '2123123412345123456' n 2
seq '123123412345123456' n 3
seq '23123412345123456' n 4
seq '3123412345123456' n 5
seq '123412345123456' n 6
seq '23412345123456' n 7
seq '3412345123456' n 8
seq '412345123456' n 9
seq '12345123456' n 10
seq '2345123456' n 11
seq '345123456' n 12
seq '45123456' n 13
seq '5123456' n 14
seq '123456' n 15
seq '23456' n 16
seq '3456' n 17
seq '456' n 18
seq '56' n 19
seq '6' n 20
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']


Так гораздо лучше. Только медленно. Не надо менять строку, из неё можно вырезать подходящие кусочки:
...
for i in range(len(seq) - k_mer + 1):

    k = seq[i:i + k_mer]
    if k not in list and k != '':
        list.append(k)
    n += 1
...

Стало быстрее, но k not in list всё ещё может тормозить на длинных списках. Заменим на множество, код станет быстрее и проще:
seq = input().upper()
k_mer = int(input())
s = set()
for i in range(len(seq) - k_mer + 1):
    s.add(seq[i:i + k_mer])
lst = list(s)
print(lst)


$ echo -e 'AFGTYAFTGAF\n1' | python temp.py
['A', 'G', 'Y', 'T', 'F']

$ echo -e 'AFGTYAFTGAF\n2' | py temp.py
['TY', 'YA', 'GA', 'GT', 'TG', 'FT', 'FG', 'AF']



Спасибо большое, очень наглядно объяснили, а то не понимал почему так много откусывается-то, теперь все ясно, никаких n не нужно!

При сокращении строки внутри цикла с помощью seq = seq[n:len(seq)], строка постоянно укорачивается:
seq = input().upper()
k_mer = int(input())

unique_kmers = []

for n in range(len(seq) - k_mer + 1):
    k = seq[n:n + k_mer]  
    if k not in unique_kmers:  
        unique_kmers.append(k)

print(unique_kmers)


это ответ или новый вопрос?

Готовый консольный скрипт (сохранить в файл test.py и запустить):
import os

print("-" * 70 + "\nСписок уникальных комбинаций заданной длины из букв заданной строки:\n" + "-" * 70)

# Функция обработки строки:
def unique_substrings(v_string, v_n):

 ok = True

 if not v_string: print("Не указана строка!"); ok = False

 if ok:
  try: v_string = v_string.strip()
  except Exception as e: print(f"Недопустимое содержимое строки! Подробнее:\n{e}"); ok = False

 if ok:
  try: v_n = abs(int(v_n))
  except Exception as e: print(f"Недопустимое значение длины подстрок! Подробнее:\n{e}"); ok = False

 if ok and (v_n <= 0 or v_n > len(v_string)): print("Недопустимое значение длины подстрок!"); ok = False

 if ok:
  set_substrings = set()
  for i in range(len(v_string) - v_n + 1): set_substrings.add(v_string[i: i + v_n])
  print(f"\nСписок уникальных комбинаций букв по {v_n}:\n", list(set_substrings))

# Пример использования:
v_string = "AFGTYAFTGAF"
v_n = 4
unique_substrings(v_string, v_n)

print("\nНажмите любую клавишу для продолжения...")
os.system("pause > nul" if os.name == "nt" else "read > /dev/null")

Результат:
Список уникальных комбинаций букв по 4:
 ['FGTY', 'AFGT', 'FTGA', 'TYAF', 'TGAF', 'GTYA', 'YAFT', 'AFTG']

